# Why is my created_at column showing up as yesterday? (in Rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, time

I have 2 columns in a record

```
updated_at: 2017-01-26 16:14:14.479386
created_at: 2017-01-26 00:00:00
```

Why is it when I write:

```
<%= created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %>
```

It shows on on the page as **JANUARY 25, 2017**, a day behind?

What's weirder is when I change created_at to **2017-01-26 00:04:00**, it shows up as **JANUARY 26, 2017**

What in the heck is going on?

Comment: in Rails Console, Rails.configuration.time_zone - Is this set properly?

Answer (score 0):

Database records are stored at UTC, while your ActiveRecord accessor will translate that UTC date into the time zone currently in use.